# Swift, cleaner way for collecting data across screens

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have multiple screens, in which they have a `textfield(s)`. I want to collect the data from them while the user is going next on each screens. What I've tried is:

**MyViewController:**

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

var foo: MyModel = MyModel() // create instance of the model for the first time

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.destination is AnotherViewController {
        self.foo.column1 = textField.text ?? "" // update column1

        let vc = segue.destination as? AnotherViewController
        vc?.foo = self.foo // here, im passing the updated model
    }
}
}
```

**AnotherViewController:**

```
class AnotherViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

var foo: MyModel! // model is constructed already, and passed with the updated data

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.destination is AnotherAgainViewController {
        self.foo.column2 = textField.text ?? "" // update column2

        let vc = segue.destination as? AnotherAgainViewController
        vc?.foo = self.foo // im passing again the updated model
    }
}
}
```

Then basically, I'm repeating this code again and again. Is this ok in terms of maintainability and flexibility? Or is there any better way of doing this?

**PS**: I don't want to use singleton just to achieve sharing of data across, as it is not a good practice, hard to debug (specially when someone modifies it), and will result to spaghetti code. I want to achieve this is in a cleaner and maintainable way.

Comment: you can move this `self.foo.column1 = textField.text ?? ""` somewhere else to make it cleaner

Comment: What do you mean sir @Lu_? Where should I put it?

Comment: in the save/move to next screen button function probably or when editing is finished delegate method

Comment: How can I gather the data from the textfields if the storyboard is not in the foreground? Can you provide an example? Thank you.

Comment: You can have a parent view controller for the view controller of this flow, and initialize the modal once on load of first view controller of flow.

Comment: You might not want to have a singleton `model`, but you can have a `dataholder` which is a singleton and keeps references to your model objects, and creates them the first time they are referred, like the `managed object context` in code data.

Comment: @lukya also thinking for that and I will just inject it using swinject, but I guess that it is too much just to share data across only on related screens, by the way, I've found a solution, I've used the idea of Ankit and Nitish. I just modified the code of Nitish and somehow manage to make it clearer. Ill post the answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a **base controller** class and override `performSegueWithIdentifier` there :

```
class BaseController: UIViewController {

var foo: MyModel! // model is constructed already, and passed with the updated data

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.destination is AnotherAgainViewController {  // Replace if else by switch if you have many VC's
        let vc = segue.destination as? AnotherAgainViewController
        vc?.foo = self.foo
    }
}
}
```

Now in **MyViewController** :

```
class MyViewController: BaseController {

//
..
//  

// Wherever you are setting model  

self.foo = localModel    // self.foo is of BaseController

}
```

Similarly for other ViewControllers.

Comment: Oh, sure I'll give this a try, my only question here is I don't know if the model will be constructed again, which will overwrite it. Ill just test it. :D

Comment: Managed to do it with some modification, my code is posted below. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Managed to do it with some modification of the code of @Nitish:

**BaseController:**

```
class BaseController: UIViewController {

var foo: MyModel!

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.destination is BaseController {
        let vc = segue.destination as? BaseController
        vc?.foo = self.foo
    }
}
}
```

**MyViewController:**

```
class MyViewController: BaseController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        self.foo = Foo() // call initialization only on the first screen
        self.foo.column1 = foo.text ?? "" // update column1            
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender) // call the super, and also this is flexible because I don't call specific view controller here.
    }
}
```

**AnotherViewController:**

```
class AnotherViewController: BaseController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        self.foo.column2 = foo.text ?? "" // update column2            
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
    }
}
```